# How to extract string after certain occurrence of the character in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a string as shown here, and I would like to extract `1234566@2345|1234544@3456` from that string.

```
1111,AAA,9087404,20230315,VVBBFDEe,1234566@2345|1234544@3456,FALSE,,,,,
```

With `CHARINDEX` I can only look for the first comma.

Comment: Please tag the RDBMS you're using - answers will vary materially between each.

Comment: Useful articles [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Comment: I'm guessing this is `sql server` since you mention `charindex()`. You may have some luck using [`string_split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) in a `CROSS APPLY` to split this string by a comma and send each token to its own row. Then you can sniff out which row has the token you want `WHERE value LIKE '%@%|%@%` or what-have-you. It would be helpful if you share which RDBMS you are using, some sample data from the table and desired results after this SQL runs.

Comment: @JNevill   got it.. i used string_Split() and where condtion like you mentioned. thank you :-)

Comment: @unicorn Please post the answer to help future searchers.

Answer (score 1):

thank you @JNevill. All that i did is and got the output i was looking for.

```
select [value]
from (select '1111,AAA,9087404,20230315,VVBBFDEe,1234566@2345|1234544@3456,FALSE,,,,,' as string ) a
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(a.string,',')
where [value] like '%@%|%@%'
```